How can I configure Ubuntu as a server for browser access? (Moodle Project)
I'm making a class on Moodle to help my students. In this first step, my team of “developers” is very small (just 3 people). I thought about putting the site online using an old PC I have at home as a server. So my team can access the website via browser at home and then work on the Moodle project.
Can I do this through Ubuntu or Ubuntu Server? Does anyone have a good tutorial explaining how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Using your PC as a web server is easy (Ubuntu Server comes with Apache2), but a bigger issue is that your PC will need to be accessible from anywhere on the internet. You may need to modify your internet connection (a router, a modem or both) and find a way of pointing your team's browsers to your web server, i.e. by obtaining a domain name that points to your home connection. It may be easier (but less fun) to use a hosting provider.
